# ID repetido em objetos da minha array

Tags: typescript, angular-6

Eu estou tentando atribuir um ID para cada objeto da minha array, mas quando tenho dois ou mais objetos parecidos, eles acabam recebendo a mesma ID.
Já tentei fazer por `indexOf()` e o também não funcionou.

```
this.selection.selected.forEach(servico => {
   servico.id = this.contador;
   this.adicionados.push(servico);
   this.contador++;
});
```

[image: Lista com objetos diferentes] [image: Lista com 1 objeto repetido]

Lista com objetos diferentes - 
Lista com 1 objeto repetido

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que estou a perceber, estão repetidos porque estás sempre a adicionar ao mesmo array sem o limpar primeiro.

Vê se o seguinte código resolve o teu problema

```
const novosAdicionados = [];
this.selection.selected.forEach(servico => {
    servico.id = this.contador;
    novosAdicionados.push(servico);
    this.contador++;
 });

 this.adicionados = novosAdicionados;
```

Caso não seja isto, é necessário que dês mais informação/codigo para te ajudar.